# MySQLRoleProvider error on Asp.NET MVC Application but using SQLServer only

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm new on this. I got a sample project that runs perfectly on another pc but get an error when running on my own pc. I changed the connection string and restored the database only. I am using a SQLServer connection, but when I run the project it shows a MySQLRoleProvider error. I searched web.config for this configuration but it isn't there. How can I solve this issue?

The message:

```
`Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=+++' or one of its dependencies.

<add name="MySQLRoleProvider" 
     type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=***" 
     connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" 
     applicationName="/"/>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the MySQL Connector binaries first for this to work.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

If after installation you still face problems, verify that the dll's are declared in machine.config file of the framework version that you're running.

Comment: Simple and sweet! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add following to config file...

```
<configuration>

  <!--Other omited-->
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <clear />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
      description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
      type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, 
        Version=6.6.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

  <!--Other omited-->


</configuration>
```